# Commission from affiliates

Tags: halal-haram

Assalam aleikum. I am a housewife and trying to earn online. There are websites which pay for answering surveys, watching short videos and ads .... . We can also add affiliates and earn 5% or 10% from their earnings.
Is this commission from affiliates  halah ?
Thank you